How to prevent changing sections and clicking anywhere in the window that section from moving the previous section in javascript html css
How to prevent changing sections and clicking on that section from moving the section, what I want is to prevent clicking on any part of the window from moving to another section, otherwise it should stay there. In the gif there is that strange behavior, how I avoid it and use event.preventDefault(); in the document but it still does it or what am I doing wrong could you tell me



var sections = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.section'));
var menuItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sec'));
var currentIndex = 0;

function updateMenu() {
  menuItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index === currentIndex) {
      item.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}

function navigateTo(index) {
  if (index >= 0 && index < sections.length) {
    currentIndex = index;
    window.scrollTo(0, sections[currentIndex].offsetTop);
    updateMenu();
  }
}

updateMenu(); // Actualiza el menú inicialmente

// Evita que la página salte o se desplace al hacer clic en cualquier parte de ella
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden; /* Evita el desplazamiento al hacer clic */
}
.fixed-menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
}
.sec {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.sec .indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.sec.active .indicator {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#section1 { background-color: #f00; }
#section2 { background-color: #0f0; }
#section3 { background-color: #00f; }
#section4 { background-color: #ff0; } 
<div class="fixed-menu">
  <div class="menu-content">
    <div>Logo</div>
    <div class="sec" onclick="navigateTo(0)">Sección 1<div class="indicator"></div></div>
    <div class="sec" onclick="navigateTo(1)">Sección 2<div class="indicator"></div></div>
    <div class="sec" onclick="navigateTo(2)">Sección 3<div class="indicator"></div></div>
    <div class="sec" onclick="navigateTo(3)">Sección 4<div class="indicator"></div></div>
    <div>Login</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="section1" class="section">Sección 1</div>
<div id="section2" class="section">Sección 2</div>
<div id="section3" class="section">Sección 3</div>
<div id="section4" class="section">Sección 4</div>




im not sure but it appears to work anyway? https://jsbin.com/hobepaweci/edit?js,output

That's perfect, that's what I wanted, but could you tell me what caused that jump or how you corrected it so I can keep an eye on it?

I realized later that it was fine, the error appears just when I use it with ide brackets
